# How to get project list if delete .metadata accidentally

Tags: java, eclipse

if `.metadata` directory is deleted, is there a way to recover the Eclipse project list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After you have re-created your workspace, you can re-add projects to your workspace by following these steps:

- Select `File :: Import :: Other :: General :: Existing Projects into Workspace`
- `Browse` for the root directory (if the projects share a common parent, like the workspace directory, select that)
- Check all the projects you want to re-import and click `Finish`

Answer (score 1):

Now that you know [where the projects are stored within said metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119008/where-are-project-stored-in-eclipse)..., no there isn't a way to recover that list.
You need to re-import those projects in your workspace.

The name of those project comes from their respective `.project` file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try restarting the eclipse IDE. This help to resolve issue me in my case.