# How to Import Projects in eclipse, when, after selecting root directory, you have a project with an un-checkable box?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

After re-installing eclipse, I am attempting to import some previously existing projects which are stored on OneDrive for convenience.

After I select 'Import Projects' from the 'File' menu, and then select the 'Select root directory' radial button, I see my Project listed under the Projects window.  However, I am unable to select the checkbox next to my project name.  Similarly, the 'select All' button does nothing.

[image: Valid XHTML]

How can I select my project and complete the project import process?

Comment: if project is already imported in workspace then you can't import that's why it's not allowing you.

Comment: @pratikpatel thank you, but if that's the case then how can I access the project?  When I attempt to click on the project in the workspace explorer on the left I get the following error: "The project description file (.project) from 'Program 1' is missing.  This file contains important information about the project. The project will not function properly until the file is restored."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531532/the-project-description-file-project-for-my-project-is-missing can help you

Comment: See if you deleted .project file.

Comment: @arundeepchohan after checking both the metadata folder as well as the actual project folder, I can see that the .project file does exist in both places, however I am still getting the ".project file missing" error unfortunately

Comment: Ok then Delete the project (Not from disk space). Then File-> New-> Project -> Provide Name and Source destination and it should work.

Comment: @arundeepchohan Thank you, this worked for me.  If you care to post an answer I will be glad to select yours as best. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Delete the project (Not from disk space). Then File-> New-> Project -> Provide Name and Source destination and it should work
```

Comment: arundeep chohan's solution worked for me.  I will add that, after deleting the projects from my workspace, I was able to re-import them using: File -> Import... -> Existing Projects from Workspace -> Next -> Select root directory -> Browse -> MyProgramFolder -> Select Folder -> Finish.  Much thanks to arundeep chohan